# Convert epoch to UTC date from json, nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

Hi I've the following json in flowfile: `{"destination.port":"0000","network.packets":"1","event.end":"1563361839","source.address":"1.2.2.1","message":"OK","server.address":"ip-1-2-2-3.ec2.internal","event.action":"ACCEPT","event.module":"s3bucket","source.port":"478","network.protocol":"6","cloud.account.id":"123456","event.type":"data","organization.id":"Fusion","destination.address":"1.2.2.2","network.bytes":"60","event.start":"1563361837","event.kind":"2","host.id":"eni-06f72","timestamp":"2019-07-17T11:16:39.792Z"}` with event.end and event.start as epoch.

I'm using nifi-1.9.2.
Help me convert the epoch to date in UTC and replace the same. I have tried using `updateAttribute` processor with `/event.start=${event.start:format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")}`, didn't go right. I have done some reading for a processor but couldn't. Thanks

Comment: the flow file attributes and json as a content of the file - are different things. UpdateAttributes works only with attributes and keeps content unchanged.

Comment: @daggett yeah, gotta know this while I try. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source to your problem is how you try to extract `event.start` from the JSON. The expression language is used for manipulating FlowFile's attributes, and not content of your FlowFile.

If this JSON is in the content of your FlowFile, then use `EvaluateJsonPath`, with `Destination` property set to `flowfile-attribute` and new custom property named `event.start` set to `$['event.start']`.
And now that you have it as attribute, transfer it to `JoltTransformJSON` with `Jolt Transformation DSL` set to `Modify - Overwrite` and `Jolt Specification` set to:

```
{
  "event.start": "${event.start:append('000'):format('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')}"
}
```

The appended 3 zeros are since epoch in NiFi is in milliseconds.