# how to create specific array in jolt

Tags: arrays, json, apache-nifi, jolt

im in learning process to learn jolt,  but quite hard to master as there is array and the output must be the exactly the same as example below.

**how to create a jolt spec form  ,
the json input is like this** :

```json
[
  {
    "encounter_date": "1616509603296",
    "id_no": "671223025051",
    "patient_id": "MAEPS-PID-2100003716",
    "patient_mrn": "MAEPS-MRN-2100003815",
    "first_name": "MOHD RAZALI "
  },
  {
    "encounter_date": "1621324591194",
    "id_no": "950224145647",
    "patient_id": "MAEPS-PID-2100030302",
    "patient_mrn": "MAEPS-MRN-2100030401",
    "first_name": "MUHAMMAD FADDIL BIN YASIN"
  }
]
```

**expected output is like this :**

```json
{
  "forms": [
    {
      "visit": {
        "patientId": "MAEPS-PID-2100003716",
        "Patientmrn": "MAEPS-MRN-2100003815",
        "encounterDate": "2021-03-23 22:26:43.296"
      },
      "person": {
        "firstname": "MOHD RAZALI ",
        "identifications": [
          {
            "idNo": "671223025051"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "visit": {
        "patientId": "MAEPS-PID-2100030302",
        "Patientmrn": "MAEPS-MRN-2100030401",
        "encounterDate": "2021-05-18 15:56:31.194"
      },
      "person": {
        "firstname": "MUHAMMAD FADDIL BIN YASIN",
        "identifications": [
          {
            "idNo": "950224145647"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**i'm new to jolt and require guidance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with just a single `shift` operation as below.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "patient_id": "forms[&1].visit.patientId",
        "patient_mrn": "forms[&1].visit.Patientmrn",
        "encounter_date": "forms[&1].visit.encounterDate",
        "first_name": "forms[&1].person.firstname",
        "id_no": "forms[&1].person.identifications[0].idNo"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thank u so much , i now only have the issue regarding date .. but other than that ur solution is great, thank you so much

Comment: @YaminAzlan perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57087780/5841306) might help you for the date formatting.